# Return a Text Value for query against a numerical value in an adjacent cell?

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to use an Array Forumla to look up a second worksheet, but instead of returning a value or a True / False answer, I want to return the text label for an adjacent cell. For example instead of checking as to whether or not these cells have a value in them, I would want the label on D11 back.

=(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(D11&E11;"*"&"1")))

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it.

=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Numbers!I2:I<6,Numbers!C2:C, "")))